# Ext.tree.TreeNode setting tooltip dynamic

Tags: javascript, extjs

I was wonder is it possible to add dynamicly tooltiptext to a specific tree node, i've tryied to set qtip property but with no success....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With myNode being a TreeNode you can try something like :

```
myNode.ui.textNode.setAttribute('ext:qtip', 'My dynamic tooltip');
```

You probably know that but don't forget to activate QuickTips :

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
```